# ngx-bootstrap listLocales gets only 2 locales

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I tried to use the localisation feature in ngx-bootstrap:

I used the exact demo from the documentation:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#locales

Since i want to localize the date picker.
I get only 2 locales in my app 'sv' & 'en'.

Did anybody get the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

List locales shows only loaded and registered locales,
It's desired behaviour to reduce bundle size of your application

Eventually our date manipulation lib will be published separetly,
As for now datepicker locales demo contains all available locales

Comment: I still have a problem, Importing registering one locale works great once I try to load more then one locale the solution breaks.

Comment: Stackblitz sample to reproduce?